# Kernel Power Failure - Regular and Periodic pattern

Tags: windows, windows-10, reboot, kernel, event-viewer

My PC is freezing and then rebooting.  Event viewer reports a kernel power (event ID: 41).
It happens every 3 days in the evening.  Given this periodic pattern, does this help diagnose the issue?
I don't know how to diagnose this and any help is much appreciated.

[Event Viewer Screenshot - 3 kernel power logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDp9I.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Event ID 41 is generated during bootup when the computer has not shutdown due to a crash or power failure. Therefore it has no information in it (except for a crash that successfully recorded).

Click *Start - Settings - Update and Security - Troubleshoot* - and choose the *Blue Screen* troubleshooter.

Type `Control` in Run dialog (Winkey + R). Make sure view is set to *Categories*, and type *Problem Reports* in the search box then choose *View All Problem Reports*. Review the crashes. Especially ones that happen every three days.

You can also download this Microsoft tool that can analyse dump files. In addition to being for programmers it comes with a module called *Analyse Only* for more ordinary people. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210